# is there any way of removing pairs with opposite sign in data set?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set as below. If cancel is "Y" then dollar is negative and viceversa. 
 From the data, I want to remove pairs having same magnitute of dollar but different sign (of course there should be different sign in cancel value) in same id.

df

```
rownumber id1    cancel      dollar 
    1       1      Y          -50     
    2       1      N           10     
    3       1      N           50     
    4       2      N           14.4     
    5       2      Y          -23.5     
    6       2      N           23.5     
    7       3      Y          -15.5     
    8       3      N           15.5   
    9       4      Y           -20.5
```

Therefore, this is my desired output.

df_desired

```
rownumber id1    cancel      dollar 
    2       1      N           10     
    4       2      N           14.4     
    9       4      Y           -20.5
```

Probably, I can do it by using for loop but data is too big to do it. 
Is there any simple way ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a negative sign iff `cancel = Y`, why not simply store the absolute value in `dollar`? Then, you can just take rows with a unique value for cancel + dollar. After filtering, you can add back in the negative signs if you want.

If that's not an option for whatever reason, you can still do it in O(2) time if you have enough memory to build a hashset out of your data: For each row, insert `dollar` into a hashset. Then iterate again and filter out all of the values where your hashset contains `-dollar`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eric.M notes, you can do this by looking for repeated rows after taking the absolute value of `dollar`:

```
df[with(df, ave(rownumber, list(id1, abs(dollar)), FUN=length)==1 ),]
#  rownumber id1 cancel dollar
#2         2   1      N   10.0
#4         4   2      N   14.4
#9         9   4      Y  -20.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
v <- unlist(aggregate(dollar~id1, df, 
              function(x) !(duplicated(abs(x)) | duplicated(abs(x), fromLast = T)))$dollar)
df[which(v),]

#  rownumber id1 cancel dollar
#2         2   1      N   10.0
#4         4   2      N   14.4
#9         9   4      Y  -20.5
```

---

`!(duplicated(abs(x)) | duplicated(abs(x), fromLast = T))` does exactly what you want after grouping by `id1` using `aggregate`.

OR

(thanks to @thelatemail for pointing this out):

```
tmp <- interaction(df$id1, abs(df$dollar))
df[!(duplicated(tmp) | duplicated(tmp, fromLast = T)),]
```

Comment: You could also do - `tmp <- interaction(df$id1, abs(df$dollar)); df[!(duplicated(tmp) | duplicated(tmp, fromLast = T)),]` using the same back-and-forth duplicated logic.

Answer (score 0):

since you tagged it `dplyr`, we could use `dplyr` like this:

```
df %>% group_by(id1, abs(dollar)) %>% filter(sum(dollar) != 0)

  rownumber   id1 cancel dollar `abs(dollar)`
      <int> <int>  <chr>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1         2     1      N   10.0          10.0
2         4     2      N   14.4          14.4
3         9     4      Y  -20.5          20.5
```

if the legacy grouping `abs_dollar` column is distracting append `%>% ungroup() %>% select(-5)`